# Convert text content to JSON using CSV node in NODE_RED?

Tags: node.js, node-red

Can any one help me how can we pass input with multiple lines to CSV node which has different columns/elements for each line.

**I have a text file with below content**

```
H|1|2|3|$|4|4
D|3|4|5
D|4|4|6
D|2|3|4
```

Here,how can we pass columns names for **H-header,D-details** differently to CSV node which generated JSON.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is to use a switch node to split lines based on the first character and then run those lines through 2 separate CSV nodes.

[image]

The 2 CSV node can contain the header names for different line types.

The switch node should be configured something like this:

[image]

You can then combine the 2 legs of the flow again to consume the different messages for the output of the CSV nodes.